Nested RMap using Redisson and Java
I am currently working on a project and using Java and Redisson. I am leveraging a local cached map to improve read latencies. However, I would like to restructure it so that the value is a map itself. I have read online here from that its best to use a nested RMap.
I can create the overall structure as follows:
RMap<Integer, RMap<String, Integer>> exampleMap = this.redissonClient.getLocalCachedMap(...);

However, how do I go about populating this map? Particularly, how do I go about populating the RMap values within exampleMap? I can't seem to find any documentation online for it. Any guidance or insights would be greatly helpful.
